# How to get stack to run extra commands when building a haskell package?

Tags: haskell, build, doctest, haskell-stack, hlint

I had made a script for compiling my haskell programs (so far just simple scripts consisting in a single source file) that contained, before the call to ghc, the following lines:

```
echo "Running hlint"
hlint ${1}
echo "Running scan"
~/.cabal/bin/scan -j False ${1}
echo "Running doctest"
~/.cabal/bin/doctest ${1}
```

(`${1}` referring to the single .hs source file.)

How to get some equivalent checking done when using stack to manage and build my programs?

I would like to setup some global configuration that would have these commands run automatically on the source code when calling `stack build` in any of my projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack provides a `--exec` flag which allows you to do this. Check the ['Flags' documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/build_command/#flags) for a full example, but we can see a command like:

```
$ stack build --test --exec "echo Hi!"
```

Where `--exec` is the 'do other stuff' and `--test` runs the tests.

Related to your example, it could look like:

```
stack build \
  --exec "hlint foo" \
  --exec "~/.cabal/bin/scan -j False bar"
  --exec "~/.cabal/bin/doctest baz"
```